# Binding a context menu header to the selected item of a ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, binding, contextmenu

I am trying to bind the header of the context menu to a property of the selected item of the respective `ListView`. The objects of the `ItemsSource` have an `IsDuplicate` property. Any idea what is wrong?

```
<ListView x:Name="AthletesListView" ItemsSource="{Binding FoundAthletes}">
   <ListView.ContextMenu>
      <ContextMenu>
         <MenuItem Name="AddorEditAthleteMenuItem" 
                   Header="{Binding SelectedItem.IsDuplicate, 
                          ElementName=AthletesListView,
                          Converter={StaticResource FoundAthletesAddEditMenuItemConverter}}" 
                   Click="AddAthleteMenuItem_Click"/>
      </ContextMenu>
   </ListView.ContextMenu>
```

Below the error message:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=AthletesListView'. BindingExpression:Path=SelectedItem; DataItem=null; target element is 'MenuItem' (Name='AddorEditAthleteMenuItem'); target property is 'Header' (type 'Object')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ContextMenu` is not part of the same visual tree as the associated `ListView`, because it is displayed in a different window. Consequently, relative source and element name bindings don't work.

Instead, you can use the [`PlacementTarget`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.contextmenu.placementtarget?view=net-5.0) of the `ContextMenu`, which is the `ListView`.

```
<MenuItem Name="AddorEditAthleteMenuItem" 
          Header="{Binding PlacementTarget.SelectedItem.IsDuplicate, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}, Converter={StaticResource FoundAthletesAddEditMenuItemConverter}}"
          Click="AddAthleteMenuItem_Click"/>
```

Comment: Many thanks - will check tomorrow if it works for me. Indeed I also tried Relative source which did not work either...